# scrapy exceptions.TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

When I was in use scrapy collection into Mysql and the have some problems, hope everyone to give solutions, thank you。
pipelines.py type of error：

```
2013-12-06 18:07:02+0800 [-] ERROR: Unhandled error in Deferred:
2013-12-06 18:07:02+0800 [-] Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 524, in __bootstrap
        self.__bootstrap_inner()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
        self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/threadpool.py", line 191, in _worker
        result = context.call(ctx, function, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
        return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
        return func(*args,**kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/enterprise/adbapi.py", line 448, in _runInteraction
        result = interaction(trans, *args, **kw)
      File "/home/hugo/spider/spider/pipelines.py", line 39, in _conditional_insert
        tx.execute('INSERT INTO book_updata values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' ,(item['name'][i], item['siteid'][i], item['page_url'][i], item['page_title'][i], time.time()))
    exceptions.TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

error：exceptions.TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

and the code：

```
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/item-pipeline.html
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy import log
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
from scrapy.http import Request  
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem 
from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import ImagesPipeline 
import time  
import MySQLdb  
import MySQLdb.cursors
import socket
import select
import sys
import os
import errno

class MySQLStorePipeline(object):
    def __init__ (self):

        self.dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('MySQLdb', 
              db = 'test', 
              user = 'root', 
              passwd = '153325', 
              cursorclass =MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor,  
              charset = 'utf8', 
              use_unicode = False
       )
    def process_item(self,item, spider):
        query = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._conditional_insert,item)  
        return item
    def _conditional_insert (self, tx, item):
        for i in range(len(item['name'])):
            tx.execute("select * from book where name = '%s'" % (item['name'][i]))
            result = tx.fetchone()
            #(name, page_url, page_title, siteid, date) 
            if result:
                for i in range(len(item['name'])):
                    tx.execute('INSERT INTO book_updata values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' ,(item['name'][i], item['siteid'][i], item['page_url'][i], item['page_title'][i], time.time()))
                    log.msg("\n ====Old novel: %s is update!==== \n" % item['name'][i], level=log.DEBUG)
            else:
                log.msg("\n ===New novel: %s is into db==== \n" % item['name'][i], level=log.DEBUG)
                tx.execute("INSERT INTO book (name, category, page_url, page_title, author, img_url, intro, state, time) values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (item['name'][i], item['category'][i], item['page_url'][i], item['page_title'][i], item['author'][i], item['img_url'][i], item['intro'][i], item['state'][i], int(time.time())))
    def handle_error(self, e):
        log.err(e)
```

Comment: what is item in this code?

Comment: you need to show as your spiders.py and items.py as well to better understand your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that one of your `item[xxx]` in `tx.execute('INSERT INTO book_updata ...)` is an *int* rather than a *list* or *dict*. So check data format in `item` to see if the format of the data is wrong.